# Pandas to_datetime not formatting as expected

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame with a column 'Date' with data type datetime64. The values are in YYYY-MM-DD format. 
How can I convert it to YYYY-MM format and use it as a datetime64 object itself.
I tried converting my datetime object to a string in YYYY-MM format and then back to datetime object in YYYY-MM format but it didn't work.

Original data = 1988-01-01.

Converting datatime object to string in YY-MM format

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

This worked as expected, my column value became

1988-01

Converting the string back to datetime object in Y-m format

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format= '%Y-%m')
```

I was expecting the Date column in YYYY-MM format but it became YYYY-MM-DD format.

1988-01-01

Can you please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is [expected behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime), in datetimes the year, month and day arguments are required.

If want remove `days` need month period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
```

---

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format= '%Y-%m').dt.to_period('M')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(['1988-01-01','1999-01-15'])})
print (df)
        Date
0 1988-01-01
1 1999-01-15

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
print (df)
     Date
0 1988-01
1 1999-01
```